# Chosen (chzn) vs iPad 3: Short pages flicker/bounce when a chzn select is touched

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-chosen, ipad-3, visual-glitch

This is difficult to articulate and I wonder if anyone else has had this issue.

**Have a look at [this preview](http://jsbin.com/awinil/1) on an iPad3.**

**1)** Click any of the CHZN dropdowns. (selects)

-- You'll notice a screen flicker.. or a bounce.. whatever you want to call it.

**2)** Now try clicking the button that says: "MORE PAGE" (for testing, I made this button add 3000px to the footer's padding-bottom)
Then try to use one of the CHZN dropdowns again.

-- No flicker now! Just a smooth scroll animation.

**So...** it seems when the page is short and when one of the CHZN controls gets focus or is touched. It's as if it wants to scroll to the object, but if the object is already near the top and there isn't any vertical scrolling available below "the fold" it bounces! It's quite ugly and violent and you can imagine it destroys the smoothness of any simple home page with a chzn control on it.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ios update a year ago fixed this isssue, fyi.